# Bootstrap input text in form-control is taking some unwanted margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to create a form using bootstrap.
When tried to create it gave unwanted margin on the right of the input. I have tried to check out the margins in the browsers console. It might be a minor thing but unable to figure it out. I am also attaching a screen shot.

```
   <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="tenantForm" class="container">
                        <center> <h4>Login Form</h4></center>
                        <hr />

                        <form>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
             </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

[image: This the issue happening with the input text]

Comment: can you remove the class="container" and let me know if it works to post as answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove the class `container` from `<div id="tenantForm" class="container">`

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div id="tenantForm">
        <center>
          <h4>Login Form</h4>
        </center>
        <hr />

        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
          </div>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `class="container"` from `<div id="tenantForm" class="container">`, live demo here

https://codepen.io/msolimans/pen/KXjGBz

Comment: I have removed the class="container" but didnot work.

Comment: did you check the demo, can you reproduce it in demo, may be you have different styles in the page itself.